# SQL append column at the bottom of another column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

What is the best way to append a column at the bottom of another column? So it would look something like this:

```
column_a   column_b
a          e  
f          k
c          m

new_column
a
f
c
e
k
m
```

All i can really find is answers on how to merge two column into one and this is with CONCAT() but nothing about pasting two column ontop of each other.

Comment: Did you have a look at `UNION`?

Comment: There is no such thing "as the bottom".  SQL tables represent unordered sets.

Comment: _unordered ~sets~ bags in pretty much all the implementations._

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the order, you could use something like this.

```
with col_a as (select 'a' as column_a union select 'f' union select 'c'),
     col_b as (select 'e' as column_b union select 'k' union select 'm')
select 1 as num_order,
       column_a
from col_a
union all
select 2 as num_order,
       column_b
from col_b
order by num_order;
```

Yields:

```
1,a
1,c
1,f
2,e
2,k
2,m
```

If the order is irrelevant you can omit the `num_order` attribute.